# How can I bind a text field from my DataTable to a dropdownlist in a DataGrid? (NOT A GRIDVIEW)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that contains 4 columns. One of the columns is a DropDownList. When I bind my DataTable to my DataGrid all the columns have data except the DropDownList is blank.

```
string wc = WC_Id.Text;
string SQL1 = @"SELECT * FROM SFD100011 WHERE WC_Id = '" + wc + "'";

dgPrintTicket.DataSource = Lib.GetDataTable(SQL1);
dgPrintTicket.DataBind();
```

All the columns get bound except the DropDownList stays empty.

Any Ideas?

thanks

Comment: My idea would be to show us your code.

Comment: What is the technology wpf? Winforms? Asp.Net?

Comment: @OmegaMan This is ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION IN C#.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn - sorry I added the section of code where i Bind the datatable to the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Because you added a DropDownList to the cells in one collumn, these cells are not displaying values any more. Instead you have to fill the embedded DropDownList with values.

For testing purposes remove the DropDownList and try if the DataGrid is filled.

Comment: The column was a label before i converted it to a dropdownlist. All four columns were the same, but I needed to change this column to a DDL so to be able to selection option for "Machine_Id". So I know it worked before but now that its a DDL how do I bind the Machine_Id field to it?